# Problem understanding basic properties on algebraic affine varieties.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I, beginning studying basic algebraic geometry by my own, and every book or notes Ive been reading began proving the following:

For an algebraic closed field $K$;

1.- $\emptyset$ and  the whole affine space,$\mathbb{A}_{K}^{n}$ , are algebraic affine varieties.

2.- If $V(I)$ and $V(J)$ are algebraic affine varietes then $V(I) \cup V(J)$ is  algebraic affine variety.

3.- If $\lbrace V(I_{i})\rbrace_{i \in I}$ is a family of algebraic affine variety, then $\bigcap_{i \in I} V(I_{i})$ is and algebraic affine variety.

For $1$, the sources Im reading prove the statement by mention that $\emptyset=V(1)$ and $\mathbb{A}_{K}^{n}=V(0)$, but I dont understand what $V(1)$ or $V(0)$ means?

For $2$, they prove $V(I) \cup V(J)=V(I \cap J)$ and I understand how they proved this double contention. But I dont understand why this proves  $V(I) \cup V(J)$ is and algebraic variety.

For $3$, they prove $\bigcap_{i \in I} V(I_{i})= V(\sum_{i \in }I_{i})$ but as two what I dont understand is why this proves arbitrary intersection of algebraic affine varieties is indeed and algebraic variety.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Here, the author means $V((1))$ and $V((0))$, respectively where $(0), (1)$ are ideals.

2) & 3) Recall the definition of an algebraic variety. For 2) you show that $V(I) \cup V(J)$ is of the form $V(\cdot)$, namely $V(I \cap J)$. Varieties are defined to be sets of the form $V(\cdot)$. The same thing happens in 3).

Comment: Thanks a lot! (2) and (3) are now clearly but still dont undestand your point on (1) @Qi Zhu

Comment: E.g. $V(0)$ is supposed to mean $V(I)$ where $I = (0) = \{0 \}$, the ideal generated by $0$.

Comment: So $V((1))=V(K[x_{1},...,x_{n}])$ which clearly is equal to $\emptyset$ , right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. :-)

Comment: Truly aprecciate your help! @Qi Zhu